# How apps like booking/web based works

Tags: android

I recently started programming in Android, and I already have done some easy apps, but today I want to ask you how some apps are done, to can be able to develop some advanced app in future.

In particular, I want to know how the apps like Booking, Airbnb, Couchsurfing or Worldpackers and much more existing apps like them in the market work.

- I assume that they are web based applications, and maybe have some database from where retrieve data to show results in the webside and in the app, and it also reload this database from website or app?
- Is it some software architectural pattern (I don't know the name) for this type of apps I can take a look at and learn?
- Do you know if exist some recommended framework which can help you to develop this type of apps?

This are my questions, basically please help me to understant a little more about this kind of code. If you know some app example name, it is also welcome.

Comment: You could try looking at some open source apps on Github. There are some examples [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture) or [here](https://github.com/WhisperSystems/Signal-Android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The companys that offers those apps have web services that serves datas trough Http/Https to be consumed by applications.

Android uses URLConnection to download data, and libraries like GSON to parse JSON data and DOM for XML and stores internally on SQLite to be displayed to users.